# Pipeline script get commiter on gitlab

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

We have just started to use *Jenkins* to build for our projects.
I'm figuring out how to get committer on *Gitlab* in pipeline script.
Here is the script I came up to right now:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: ':origin/development']], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [[$class: 'AuthorInChangelog']],  submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'gitlab-jenkins-ssh-key', url: 
        'git@192.168.100.890:root/hello-world-example.git']]])
```

I suppose `AuthorInChangelog` can help me to get committer on Gitlab but it didn't. Please let me know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: This is how to checkout the code. How are you trying to get/use the commiter? More information (i.e. pipeline code) on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The following groovy function will return the name of the committer:

```
def getCommitter(){
  cmtrws = sh(returnStdout: true, script:'''
      git show -s --format=\'%ce\' | tr -d "'" | cut -d@ -f1
  ''').trim()
  return cmtrws
}
```

In order to use it:

```
def committer = getCommitter()
```

Or if you prefer to use a bash block:

```
committer=$(git show -s --format=\'%ce\' | tr -d "'" | cut -d@ -f1)
```